# Testing for string inclusion on Lists and Tuples

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I'm trying to test for substrings in two tuples or lists elementwise.  Here is an example:

Lists:

```
x = ['foo', 'bar']
y = ['foofoo', 'barbar']
```

I would like to see if x[0] is contained in y[0] and if x[1] is contained in y[1].  So I've tried:

```
x in y
```

Evaluates to False. And

```
[a in b for a,b in x,y]
```

Evaluates to [False, False].  Yet, I can do this elementwise,

```
x[0] in y[0]
```

Evaluates to True.  This is the exact same case for tuples (x = ('foo','bar')...)

I would love to see an output like

```
x <magic element-wise string contain function> y
['True', 'True']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
[a in b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

Comment: Pass that list (or better, the generator expression that generates it) to `all`, and you have a complete answer. (At least, I get the impression that the OP would pass the resulting list to `all`.)

Comment: @chepner: The example at the end of the question shows that the OP wants a list of the individual componentwise comparisons.